# Which Boost package do I need for bpstl::allocator?

Tags: boost

I have inherited some code which uses `bpstl::allocator`. Obviously, my predecessor had certain Boost libraries installed and I do not.

Which (Linux) package do I need to install in order for the code to compile?

I can't find a DoxyGen or other navigable Boost documentation online.

Comment: Lol at "navigable documentation". I'm tempted to ask whether you have no navigable google either :)

Comment: Plus one. Silly me. I missed the (easily missable) search box :-)  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely, `bpstl` is just a namespace alias. If I were to guess, I'd say

- boost pool
- boost container
- boost interprocess

There's not a wellknown library that uses `bpstl` as a namespace (not even obsolete, that I remember) so, in all likelihood, such aliases can be found in the adjacent code base (headers) next to that code you inherited. It's gonna take some archaeology, but grep your way to it!

---

On debian-like Linuxen, by far the easiest way to get some mainstream version of boost installed is by

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

---

Boost "navigable" documentation online is here: **http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0**

Comment: Well, the actual code line reads `bpstl::vector<DeviceProperty, bpstl::allocator<DeviceProperty> > DevList;`, so I am guessing Boost Package Standard Template Library. I searched the docs for `vector` and, not surprisingly, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector.htm say that it is in `Vector.hpp`. There are many files of such name, but only two contain the word `allocator`, both in comments. So, I am still stuck.

Comment: The problem is assuming that it is boost. That makes little sense actually. Can't you just replace with std vector/allocator or boost::container::*? Sounds like it might be something obsolete

Comment: std::vector worked, thanks. But, it turned out to be an unused declaration anyway, so I just commented it out.

Comment: Argh!! Nooo!!! I found some code which I am not allowed to change, which uses `bpstl::vector`  What can I do? I have a tight deadline & no one seems to know about it

Comment: @Mawg like I said, use the power of grep! It's obviously not some wellknown library thing. So, if they gave you a deadline without the proper code as a starting point, you'll have to inform them that it's mision impossible. Also, just downloading (another version? of) a library from the internets and recompiling is _hardly_ "Not Changing the code". They should rely on tests in all cases, even if just changing compiler options.

Comment: My _Fingerspitzengefühl_ tells me that you just haven't found the place where it's aliased. And it's likely actually something like STLPort, or EASTL, or STXXL etc. Or indeed, std::vector. Heh. You could even drop `namespace bpstl = std;` in some strategically placed header and you don't _technically_ change those lines of code...

Comment: Turns out it _was_ an alias for `std` after all, and nothing at all to do with Boost. Case closed, with heart-felt thanks.

Comment: Yay for Fingerspitzengefühl !